# How can I import search from googlesearch?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a discord bot, but I could not import search from googlesearch when running the code below

```
import discord
import sys
import discord
from googlesearch import search

client = discord.Client()

ModeFlag = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('join')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
    global ModeFlag
    
    if message.author.bot:
        return
 
    if message.content == '!exit':
        await message.channel.send('ﾉｼ')
        sys.exit()
   
    if ModeFlag == 1:
        kensaku = message.content
        ModeFlag = 0
        count = 0
    
        for url in search(kensaku, lang="jp",num = 5):
            await message.channel.send(url)
            count += 1
            if(count == 5):
               break
    if message.content == '!google':
        ModeFlag = 1
        await message.channel.send('検索するワードをチャットで発言してね')
    if message.content == 'bot君いる？':

client.run('***')
```

I got this error

> Import "googlesearch" could not be resolved

Here is how I installed the packages `google`, `discord` and `googlesearch`.

```
pip install google & pip install discord & pip install googlesearch-python
```

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like you need to do `from googlesearch.googlesearch import GoogleSearch`. See: https://pypi.org/project/google-search/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to install and import the package `googlesearch-python` and it worked without any issue. Therefore, I guess your problem is probably due to `pip` version that you used to install. If you are using `python3`, make sure that `pip` is similar to `pip3` or you should use `pip3` to be safe.

```
pip3 install google & pip3 install discord & pip3 install googlesearch-python
```

Here is what I have done:

```
$ pip3 install googlesearch-python
$ python3 

>>> from googlesearch import search
>>> search("Google")
['https://www.google.com/', 'https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor', 'https://blog.google/', 'https://about.google/intl/en_us/products/', 'https://about.google/', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google', 'https://www.facebook.com/Google/', '/search?q=Google&num=11&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=mM5eejaz-bUIsM%252C0UCf55-GTy6fDM%252C%252Fm%252F045c7b&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kS3fhB6I4-4YGkbI-0POxk60cjoEw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi78Zfo3o3vAhXtwzgGHaFuBJYQ_B16BAhSEAI#imgrc=mM5eejaz-bUIsM']
```

Comment: It's even safer to do `python3 -mpip` instead of `pip3`; that ensures the same version of `python3` you're running is used to run `pip`/install the package, so it will definitely be visible to the same `python3` later.

Comment: Agree. Btw, please correct the syntax. It should be `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter; the space between `-m` and `pip` is purely optional (the command line parser handles it the same either way).

Comment: Ah I don't even know that. Thanks!